# MySQL Insert in table if it doesn't exist already ¿Am I doing it right?

Tags: database, mysql

While building my application with relational tables I ran into the following problem :

I have the following table, for this example named "valores":

```
-----------------------
| id  |     value     |
-----------------------
|  1  |  Unique VAL   |
|  2  |  Unique VAL2  |
-----------------------
ID = AUTOINCREMENT
VALUE = UNIQUE
```

What I'm trying to do is insert the a NEW value if it doesn't exist already, the way I'm doing it right now is:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO valores (id, value) VALUES (NULL, "Unique VAL2");
```

So it won't do anything. Because the value already exists.. now my question is:

**¿Is this the best and the fastest way to do it?**

Comment: using NULL for the auto_increment column in non-standard. remove id from the INSERT statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the best way for your scenario.

For different purposes you could use ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE or REPLACE INTO

Read more: [insert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html), [replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replace.html), [on duplicate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).